# show max date of customer

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d8bc/1)

I have to show max date of column Visit_Date
if i search on '2013-10-29' then record shows those customers have date '2013-10-29'
but in coloumn i have to show max date of customer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this ...

```
SELECT
P_Master.PID,
Visit_Date,
(SELECT MAX(Visit_Date) FROM P_Visit v WHERE v.PID = p_Master.PID) as MaxVisit
FROM P_Master
LEFT JOIN P_VISIT
ON P_Master.PID=P_VISIT.PID
WHERE CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), Visit_Date, 101) AS datetime)='2013-10-29'
```

... adds a column with the moste recent visit date

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
P_Master.PID,  
Visit_Date FROM P_Master 
LEFT JOIN P_VISIT 

on Visit_Date=(SELECT MAX(Visit_Date) FROM [dbo].[P_Visit] WHERE  P_Master.PID=P_VISIT.PID )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
P_Master.PID,  
(SELECT MAX(Visit_Date) FROM P_Master
LEFT JOIN P_VISIT ON P_Master.PID=P_VISIT.PID) AS VISIT_DATE
FROM P_Master
LEFT JOIN P_VISIT
ON P_Master.PID=P_VISIT.PID
WHERE CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), Visit_Date, 101) AS datetime)='2013-10-29'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
P_Master.PID,  
MAX(Visit_Date) FROM P_Master
LEFT JOIN P_VISIT
ON P_Master.PID=P_VISIT.PID
```

will give you the most recent visit of each Visitor